# pdflatex (TeXLive) unreadable output on linux

Tags: pdftex

I'm compiling my TeX files using pdflatex from XFCE terminal (same on XTerm). The compile log is very hard to read. It's like pdflatex doesn't break the lines, so the window is randomly filled with sentenses. Is there a way to fix it?

I'm using Debian Wheezy,

edit: here is an example

```
                            ! Package inputenc Error: Unicode char \u8:��� 
not set up for use with LaTeX.

                         See the inputenc package documentation for 
explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.

...                                              

                                                         l.73 \additional

         ? 
           ! Emergency stop.

...                                              

                                                l.73 \additional

!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
                                                         Transcript written 
on scs1_memo.log.
```

Comment: How do you read the compile log?

Comment: Just watching the output in terminal.

Comment: This might not have anything to do with TeX - LaTeX, but with your OS setup.

Comment: paste (part of) your log file here in a code block (`{}` button) so we can see if there is anything unusual

Comment: Or `pdflatex foo.tex > foo.messages`, this saves the non-error messages to the file `foo.messages`, in order keep it.

Comment: It always looks like this for me, too. I always assumed it was just a 'feature' of TeX... The log file looks much neater if you need to read much of it.

Comment: UPD. I just noticed that this happens only when i compile from VIM using keybind:
`map <F8> :!pdflatex % && xpdf -cont %:r.pdf &<CR>`
And if i run from terminal: `pdflatex myfile.tex` the output is fine and readable.

Answer (score 0):

run

```
pdflatex <file> | less
```

Comment: Hmmm... I prefer the original mess. I guess it wouldn't be so bad on a regular terminal but it really slows things down if you have to page through all the output *without* errors. And it isn't very clear how to interact with it when you get to an error, either. (I like `less` normally - just it doesn't work very well for this - at least for me.)